# Helper Module causing friday_night_issue ... RoR

Tags: ruby-on-rails, concatenation

ENV=development

Anyone any thoughts as to why

```
     def tidy_address(location)
       t_address=t_address+"<br>"+location.address1 if location.address1.present?
       t_address=t_address+"<br>"+location.address2 if location.address2.present?
       t_address=t_address+"<br>"+location.address3 if location.address3.present?
       t_address=t_address+"<br>"+location.postcode if location.postcode.present?
     end
```

is throwing an error

```
 undefined method `+' for nil:NilClass
```

I appear to be applying a method to a string , but im not sure how to resolve this

also tried

```
     ... +"<br>#{location.field}" ...
```

Boozy suggestions accepted

Answer (score -2):

Doooh ...

so this resolved it - im an old ASP hack and it was lazy

```
 def tidy_address(location)
   t_address="<br>"+location.address1 if location.address1.present?
   t_address=t_address+"<br>"+location.address2 if location.address2.present?
   t_address=t_address+"<br>"+location.address3 if location.address3.present?
   t_address=t_address+"<br>"+location.postcode if location.postcode.present?
 end
```